# symlink error with chmod

Tags: permissions, symbolic-link

After installing fastqc, tried setting the permission using:

```
chmod +x ~/miniconda3/bin/fastqc
```

But got the error:

```
chmod: cannot operate on dangling symlink '/home/usernname/miniconda3/bin/fastqc
```

What could be possibly wrong?

Comment: This means that `~/miniconda3/bin/fastqc` is a symbolic link to a file that does not exist ... please add the output of `ls -l ~/miniconda3/bin/fastqc` and the output of `stat $(readlink -f ~/miniconda3/bin/fastqc)` to your question.